# Adding Color to Code Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following which is moving new lines of data to a destination worksheet (wsdest). I tacked on the (Interior.color = RGB(10, 90, 175) portion to ensure that newly added lines are added with a specific color, so they stand out. It was working fine, but I cannot seem to get it to work with the color change.

```
With wsSource


 RowCount = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        If .Cells(i, "BH").Value = 5 Then

            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsDest.Range("A:A"), .Cells(i, "A").Value) = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Copy wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(10, 90, 175)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Try `wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Interior.Color = RGB(10, 90, 175)` instead of `wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(10, 90, 175)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below with some modifications I've made:

```
With wsSource
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- modifed this line

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        If .Cells(i, "BH").Value = 5 Then

            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsDest.Range("A:A"), .Cells(i, "A").Value) = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Copy wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' <-- modifed this line
                wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Interior.Color = RGB(10, 90, 175) ' <-- modifed this line
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Works Perfectly!